# Where can I find free designs / PSDs to practice my CSS?

Tags: css

I'm diving into CSS and would like to practice coding from PSDs.  Any sites where I can grab free designs in PSD format?

Or any other suggestions for practicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Take a
  screen shot of a website you think
  would be challenging, slice and dice
  any images needed yourself in
  Photoshop and then re-create it via
  HTML/CSS. Of course most websites are
  under copyright and you could not use
  any of their intellectual property
  (e.g. images, design, code, etc...)
  in any public manner.
- Practice/improve
  your CSS skills on the [CSS Zen
  Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/). The site
  was created in such as way that
  developers can dramatically change
  it's presentation purely with CSS.
  Look through the designs and see how
  that developer accomplished it. After
  you are done with your own design you
  can submit it to be shared.
- See if you can find a sample/demo template from one of the many template retailers on the web. Discard their HTML/CSS and recreate yourself.

You may need some "filler" content to make your design more realistic. You might try a [lorem ipsum generator](http://www.lipsum.com/).

Comment: ah good point.  I suppose I could slice from a screenshot.  Will try it!

Answer (score 1):

I may be not really helpful, but I truly remember myself struggling with no production experience.

And, as I did, the best way to get it, was to give free of charge services of html/css coding.

Comment: i've considered this, and would like to.  But even before that, I'd like have a little more confidence going in! :)

Comment: It's good to hear this, as a developer considering some pro bono work to rack up EXP points.

Answer (score 1):

as long as you're not publishing the designs as your own, copying for the purposes of education is protected as "fair-use".

## Copy Copy Copy

Practice re-creating **everything**. Read through the stylesheets of sites you like, and take notes on what elements are present in them.

Don't limit yourself to just sites like what you are planning on creating, copy completely unrelated pages too. There are many companies that will publish images of designs: copy those too.

When you've crated a clone page, start tweaking styles. Add a border here, tweak some margins there. The more you play with it, the more you'll understand it.

Also: read through the CSS specifications:

- [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/)
- [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/)
- [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

And make sure you've got a good grasp of HTML by reading the [html specs too](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html).

It can be slow. It may be boring. It will be worth it.